# Relation betwen Triebel Lizorkin and Besov spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Using the Littlewood-Paley decomposition we can define the Triebel-Lizorkin spaces as the space of tempered distributions wich the following quantity
$$
\lVert u \rVert_{F^{s,p}_q}=\lVert S_0(u) \rVert_{L^p}+\bigg\lVert \bigg( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 2^{jsq}\vert \Delta_j(u) \vert^{q} \bigg)^{1/q}\bigg\rVert_{L^p}
$$
is finite, and the Besov spaces are defined in a similar way, consisting of temperated distributions wich the quantity

$$
\lVert u \rVert_{B^{s,p}_q}=\lVert S_0(u) \rVert_{L^p}+\bigg( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 2^{jsq}\lVert \Delta_j(u) \rVert_{L^p}^{q} \bigg)^{1/q}\
$$
is finite. Here $S_0(u)=u\star \varphi_0$ and $\Delta_j(u)=u\star \psi_j$, where $\psi_j$ and $\varphi_j$ satisfy the respective L-P hyphotesis. Is a fact that

$$
B^{s,p}_{\min{(p,q)}}\subset F^{s,p}_q \subset B^{s,p}_{\max{(p,q)}}
$$

but I'm not sure why we can assert that. Specially, I'm confused when the demonstration uses the triangle inequality for asserting that if $p>q$ then

$$
\bigg\lVert \bigg( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 2^{jsq}\vert \Delta_j(u) \vert^{q} \bigg)^{1/q}\bigg\rVert_{L^p}\leq \bigg( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 2^{jsq}\lVert \Delta_j(u) \rVert_{L^p}^{q} \bigg)^{1/q}
$$

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $a_j:=2^{jsq}|\Delta_j(u)|$. Then we observe first
$$
\left\| \left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_j|^q\right)^{1/q} \right\|_{L^p}^p
=\int \left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_j|^q\right)^{p/q} dx
= \left\| \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_j|^q \right\|_{L^{p/q}}^{p/q}.
$$
Using triangle inequality, which is valid since $p/q\ge1$, we get
$$
\left\| \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_j|^q \right\|_{L^{p/q}}
\le  \sum_{j=1}^\infty \|\ |a_j|^q \|_{L^{p/q}}
= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\int |a_j|^p dx\right)^{q/p}
= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \|a_j\|_{L^p}^{q}.
$$
Combining both inequality yields
$$
\left\| \left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_j|^q\right)^{1/q} \right\|_{L^p}
\le \left\| \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_j|^q \right\|_{L^{p/q}}^{1/q}
\le \left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty \|a_j\|_{L^p}^{q} \right)^{1/q}.
$$

Comment: Thank you a lot @daw.